# Trying to get all enabled AD users to import into an excel sheet but, the Pager, Office, and Title properties are all showing up blank?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Feel free to call me stupid but for some reason my brain is not figuring this out today. The code below searches Active Directory for all enabled users and then selects the Name, username, email, Pager, Office, and Title. It will then write that information to the console. For some reason the Pager, Office, and Title properties are blank. Can anyone tell me what super obvious thing I am missing here?

```
Import-Module activedirectory


$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' | Select-Object -Property Name,samaccountname,UserPrincipalName,Pager,Office,Title
forEach ($person in $Users)
    {
    Write-Host $person
    }
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first specify which properties you want to return with `Get-ADUser`

These properties are included as a default set, and don't need to be explicitly specified

- DistinguishedName
- Enabled
- GivenName
- Name
- ObjectClass
- ObjectGUID
- SamAccountName
- SID
- Surname
- UserPrincipalName

**Example**

`Get-ADUser -Properties Name,Pager,Office,Title | Select Name,Title`

**Example to return all properties**

`Get-ADUser -Properties *`